# How to modify kernel parameters without causing Kernel panic on OS

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel

This is not a duplicate question of kernel parameters, i already cause a kernel panic on my ubuntu 14.04 distribution trying to improve the performance of Nginx and postgresql, i just want to know how to prevent this from happening again and also which are the correct values to set on my kernel configuration file according to my server.

This are the lines added to the /etc/sysctl.conf file:

```
### NGINX
#
# 16MB per socket - which sounds like a lot, but will virtually never
# consume that much.
#
net.core.rmem_max = 16777216
net.core.wmem_max = 16777216

# Increase the number of outstanding syn requests allowed.
# c.f. The use of syncookies.
net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog = 4096
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1

# The maximum number of "backlogged sockets". Default is 128.
net.core.somaxconn = 2048

### POSTGRESQL
kernel.sched_migration_cost_ns = 5000000
kernel.sched_autogroup_enabled = 0
```

Im using a droplet from Digital Ocean:

- 1 Core Processor
- 1 GB Memory Ram
- 30 GB SSD Disk

This is the tutorial that i was using:
https://tweaked.io/guide/kernel/

If everything succeded i was going to perform the changes on my production Droplet, as you can see my OS failed to boot, i have to use a Recovery ISO to restore my Kernel configuration using the Digital Ocean's Console.

What am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance for your comments.

Comment: You could use the kernel ubuntu source and modifiy it's configuration there and rebuild the package. But you will loose your change at the new kernel package updage, which should not been happen very soon on 14.04 anyway. There are means to disable that upgrade.

Comment: That could work if i only knew what to change, like i said before changing kernel parameters is not what i do best, but im more interesting in finding out what kernel parameters i can change to make nginx and postgresql work better without breaking my whole OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most likely `kernel.sched_autogroup_enabled` causes the panic, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1422016

Disabling `kernel.sched_autogroup_enabled` can be alternatively achieved by passing `noautogroup` argument to the kernel via e.g. Grub config. The following has worked for me:

1. edit `/etc/default/grub` and change `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="noautogroup"` (actually it should be GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT but GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT didn't work for me).
2. `sudo update-grub`
3. reboot and to verify the result run `cat /proc/sys/kernel/sched_autogroup_enabled`, it should print `0`

Comment: Yes, this was the answer i was looking for, i changed the variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`. After reboot it print 0 , does this mean that now i can try my kernel configuration without getting a panic attack?

Comment: @RuselFichi This means that `kernel.sched_autogroup_enabled` is now turned off, as you wanted (so you can remove `kernel.sched_autogroup_enabled` line from /etc/sysctl.conf). Other settings should not cause kernel panic (except I'm not sure about `sched_migration_cost_ns` though, haven't tried it it, but ist should be safe)